# installing @angular/compiler-cli, @angular/tsc-wrapped breaks karma-jasmine test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-compiler-cli

Running karma-jasmine test trowing an error, if `@angular/compiler-cli` installed. If I will not install `@angular/compiler-cli` test are working fine, but I need compiler-cli as I need to use ng-xi18n. If I remove `@angular/tsc-wrapped`, I can run tests, but cannot run ng-xi18n.

```
28 11 2016 14:06:52.990:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/typescript.js
28 11 2016 14:06:53.026:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/typescript.js
28 11 2016 14:06:53.031:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/fs.js
28 11 2016 14:06:53.053:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/path.js
    '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/typescript.js
                Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/typescript.js as 
    "typescript" 
from http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/test/collector.spec.js'
```

package.json:

```
.....
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    ....
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/x3tZ1Vm8WNt0WYGv2Dt7?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with @angular/tsc-wrapped, it was related with karma settings. Rearranging library loading and excluding `'node_modules/**/*spec.js'` did the trick. I have also updated plinkr repo with the new settings.